# Using handlebars or markdown to output a model property

Tags: javascript, markdown, ember.js

I have a model which defines a property with either markdown or html content.

I am wondering whether using a markdown JS library to output the info or use handlebars to generate the html output inside the view.

Any recommendations, examples will be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using a Markdown converter worked for me.

Here is my view code:

```
App.ActivityDetailsView = Em.View.extend(
  templateName :        'activity-details',
  classNames :          ['details rounded shadow'],
  rawDescriptionBinding:   'App.activityDetailsController.description',

  description: (->
    converter = new Markdown.Converter().makeHtml
    return converter(@rawDescription)
  ).property('rawDescription')

)
```

Here is the template code (note the triple handlebars {{{}}} for raw html):

```
  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="activity-details">
    {{{description}}}
  </script>
```

Here is a link to [more details and the showdown.js script](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/showdown-javascript-jquery)

Comment: Great, you may want to accept the answer just to close it out

Answer (score 5):

Ember recommends that you use your controller to decorate your model. Given this model, we want to render each of these blog posts using the appropriate rendering engine:

```
[
  { id: 1, isMD: false, md_or_html: "<p>This is HTML.</p>" },
  { id: 2, isMD: true, md_or_html: "*This is MD.*" }
]
```

You'll start by creating a route which returns that model:

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return [
          { id: 1, isMD: false, md_or_html: "<p>This is HTML.</p>" },
          { id: 2, isMD: true, md_or_html: "*This is MD.*" }
        ];
    }
});
```

Just having the model returned doesn't mean that things get rendered. You also need to make sure the template for the index route attempts to put something on the page:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
  <ul>
    {{#each}}
      <li>{{output}}</li>
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
</script>
```

You'll note that we haven't yet created an `output` property, though we've included it in our template. We need to decorate our model to add the processed HTML or Markdown output:

```
App.IndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  itemController: 'post'
});

App.PostController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  output: function() {
    var result;

    if (this.get('isMD')) {
      var converter = new Markdown.Converter();
      result = converter.makeHtml(this.get('md_or_html'));
    } else {
      result = this.get('md_or_html');
    }

    /*
    IMPORTANT!!! Ember automatically escapes HTML upon insertion.
    To actually embed the result as HTML you will need tell Ember
    that the value is safe to embed as HTML.

    DO NOT RETURN SafeStrings UNLESS THE VALUE IS TRUSTED AND SANITIZED!
    */
    return new Handlebars.SafeString(result);
  }.property('isMD', 'md_or_html')
});
```

We can't just add the `output` property to `PostController` and have everything work without telling `IndexController` to use `PostController` for each item in the model. This is accomplished by setting `itemController` on `IndexController` (think: "what controller to use for each item"). This allows us to decorate each blog post individually with the `output` property. We use a computed property to tell Ember that the value of `output` is dependent upon whether or not the post `isMD` and the body of the post. If either changes we want Ember to re-render the output.

The [complete example](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/zihabuba/1/edit) includes additional comments and details about how to extend the pattern for introspection into the post body to determine if it is HTML or MD.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar case that I handled with a dynamically inserted handlebars template: I have a field containing a template which may have content **bound to application values**.

```
Ember.View.create({
    tagName: 'span',
    classNames: ['dynamic-content'],
    template: Ember.Handlebars.compile(App.preCompileTemplate(template)),
    context: someContextObject
});
```

The `App.preCompileTemplate` function replaces bindings with valid handlebars expressions, but you could also imagine using Markdown here:

```
App.preCompileTemplate = function(template) {
    return template.replace /{(.*?)}/g, '{{context.$1}}'
}
```

Using the `context` object scopes the values that you bind into the template.